# Allowing processes that started through ssh to continue and log output in file

Tags: ssh, process, logging, background-process

So this is a bit of a multi part question, I have a vps that I connect to through ssh to run a few processes on.

I would like to be able to start the processes and close my terminal window but still be able to ssh back in and check on the processes.

I would also like each process to output whatever it prints to the terminal to a file, ideally named after the command that started it. (including flags and such)

how do I best achieve this goal?

Comment: You run the process in screen - https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/ and you log output by redirection http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly multiple ways of achieving it, but here are some of essentials:

## screen

`screen` allows to create virtual console, deattach it from your tty (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) and attach it back (`screen -r`) anytime you need.

## nohup

`nohup` is a software which allows you to run command which will ignore any hangup signal and write output of command to `nohup.out` file in `cwd`. In practice running following command thought `ssh` and then logging out will keep process working `nohup dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/null &`.

## tee

`tee` command in very simple usage works as a fork machine which write it's `stdin` to a file and to `stdout` simulateously. In your case that would be `ls -alh | tee 'ls'`. If you also want to write `stderr` to file append `2&>1` (which means "redirect `stderr` to `stdout`") to your base command.

By combining these solutions you should be able to achieve what you want.
You can also see similar answer: [8703001/1732775](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703001/1732775).